# Python selenium -send_keys or set value by JS is not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

HTML code:

```
<div class='UEclfJ _27cR_W'>
<input type ='tel' autocomplete='one-time-code' maxlength = '6'>

<input class='_1y306T _2ynKud' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>
<input class='_1y306T' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>
<input class='_1y306T' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>
<input class='_1y306T' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>
<input class='_1y306T' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>
<input class='_1y306T' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>

</div>
```

I tried remove 'readonly' before send_keys but it not works .I also set_value but it can't click the next button then.The inputs are  verification code form, six cell.I see that the class name is changeable when the element is clicked.

My code:

```
        cell_change = WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(lambda driver:self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@class, "_1y306T") and contains(@class, "_2ynKud")]'))
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly','readonly')", cell_change)
        print("remove success")
        sleep(3)
        cell_change.send_keys("1")
        sleep(1)
```

Can somebody help me solve this problem or give me some ideas ? I am very grateful to this :(
Thanks about concerning my problem.

Comment: Element you want to interact with is not a text input field! Why do you want to change its value?

Comment: I search some topics like this, the solution is removing this attr , it can be send_keys.However, this solution to my problem fails. Can you help me ?

Comment: I don't know where you got this "solution" from but if you want to interact with UI via WebDriver as user do then, obviously, removing attributes from HTML is WRONG approach

Comment: How to send_key to that element which is  not a text input field, bro :(

Comment: You need to find appropriate input field and send keys to it

Comment: Is it public page? Can you share URL?

Comment: Yeah i also think about that, but i tried a lot ways but all of them fail

Comment: yes "https://shopee.vn/buyer/login/otp" you can random phone number and click next , the otp form should appear, the form is my problem.Thank you

Comment: Sorry you can input that number "0368961735" and click "TIEP THEO", the form should appear. Thank you very much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code seem to do the trick:

```
number_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="tel"]')
number_input.find_element_by_xpath('./following-sibling::input').click()
number_input.send_keys('123456')
```

**Explanation**: to be able to enter number via `<input type="tel">` you need to click on first cell